# How can I prevent Chrome from loading a cached webpage when offline?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, service-worker, cache-control

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. The user visits the webpage, see the code below.
2. The user closes Chrome.
3. The device goes completely offline (turn all networking off manually).
4. The user re-opens the browser while completely offline.
5. Chrome automatically serves the last visited page, a saved copy of the webpage which says `Online? true`, even after hitting refresh several times.

The only thing that tells the user that she/he is looking at some stale, completely unusable copy of the web page is this in the address bar:

[image]

Non-technical users can easily miss that, and are left wondering why the page is unusable... This is bad user experience.

Browser & device: Chrome 81 on Android 6 on an Acer Iconia Tab 10 A3-40 **tablet**.

The webpage is served over HTTPS (secure connection).

Code:

```js
const setMsg = (flag) => {
  const p = document.getElementById('msg')
  p.innerHTML = '<b>Online?</b>  ' + flag
}

setMsg(navigator.onLine)

window.addEventListener("online", () => {
  setMsg(true)
})
window.addEventListener("offline", () => {
  setMsg(false)
})
```

```html
<p id='msg'> </p>
```

As far as I can tell:

- Chrome does **not** re-run *any* JavaScript in Step 5, even after hitting refresh.
- Chrome does **not** respect the `Cache-Control: private, no-store` either; double-checked.

So far, the only way I could prevent this from happening is to register a service worker. When I have a service worker registered, the JavaScript is re-run and I can properly and clearly inform the user that she/he is offline.

***Without* a service worker, how can I prevent Chrome from loading a stale, unusable webpage when offline?**

The usual "No internet" page with the dinosaur is appropriate, and that's what I was expecting with `Cache-Control: no-store`.

Comment: I dont have time to research fully right now, but have you tried adding another listener for 'pageshow' that manually runs the check? That's how you rerun JS for a back button navigation, for instance, which seems like a similar problem.

Comment: @tmdesigned No, `pageshow` doesn't help either, double-checked. As far as I can tell, Chrome does not rerun *any* JavaScript, even if you hit reload. In other words, `pageshow` fails for the same reason why my code fails: It is not re-run by the browser.

Comment: On an existing site of mine, I have cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate and it doesn't restore the page. Still, I would have thought no-store alone would do that.

Comment: @tmdesigned I have bad news for you: This version of Chrome **does** restore the page. I changed then verified that the page is served with `cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` as you suggested. Then, I cleared the browser cache completely, and repeated the experiment. Chrome happily restores the page with those cache control headers. Please test your own page as I describe it in the post, with the current version of Chrome. I am pretty sure your page will be restored too. If not: Are you serving your page over HTTPS (secure connection)?

Comment: I am on Chrome 81.0.4044.113. on Mac OS X. That's the latest version I believe. I set up a bitnami node server, HTTP only. With the default "max-age=0, no-cache, s-maxage=10." your page does restore, but shows Online? false. With "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" it does not restore at all.

Comment: @tmdesigned I believe HTTPS matters, that's why I asked in my previous comment. In any case, I appreciate your efforts and feedback.

Comment: Here is the same behavior on an HTTPS connection: https://headers.tmdesigned.com/. If you test it that should tell us whether the difference is the end-user browser, or the server-config.

Comment: @tmdesigned Yep, it restores your https page too. What happens on your device? Note that I am using a mobile device (a tablet, see the details in the question). Chrome does not restore any page on my desktop machine. As a side note: Chrome restores your page even after I cold re-boot that device.

Comment: Missed that. Out of curiosity, what happens to the count display at http://3.210.13.252/ when it's restored offline?

Comment: @tmdesigned Exactly what I expected: The counter remains frozen at the value it had when I closed the browser. And even if I hit refresh after the page was restored, the counter remains frozen. As I said, Chrome does not re-run *any* JavaScript even if you hit refresh; that's why `pageshow` and all my other attempts failed too. (As a side note: upgraded to Chrome 81, but it does not make any difference.)

Comment: That's what I expected too but the worst possible case. Not sure how to work around that. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: @tmdesigned I greatly appreciate your help and your efforts! It's not your fault that the stupid browser is so aggressive when it comes to caching. I will start a bounty on this question tonight. Maybe someone knows how to resolve this issue. Many thanks again!

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your situation but I remember that binding the unload event messed with back-forward cache some time ago, I don't know if the offline caching works in a similar manner but you could give it a try.

Comment: I had similar problems with autologin for a while ago, the scripts seem really not rerun when activating a page after being passive for a long time (not even when online). I've added a "recursive" nested timeout with a delay of an hour, and the timed function is now run when activating the page again. You could try it in the offline case too.

Comment: @JDubuis Tried both beforeunload and unload, sadly, neither of them worked. But you are right, both of them break back-forward caching, so it was worth a shot.

Comment: @Teemu It is not clear to me what you mean. Please explain the *"recursive" nested timeout* part. I think [we have already tried something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61325883/how-can-i-prevent-chrome-from-loading-a-cached-webpage-when-offline?noredirect=1#comment108555786_61325883), although I am not sure since I don't understand your suggestion. That previous attempt with `setInterval` did not work either.

Comment: "_Nested timeout_" = nested timeouts emulating `setInterval`, i.e. a timeout calling itself with another timeout. A pending timeout seems to force its associated function executed when a passive tab is activated.

Comment: @Teemu OK, thanks for the clarification. I have tried that too, and it does not work either. I have added a counter and increment it on every call so that I can be sure the code is OK. The code is 120% OK, and no, Chrome does not care. The counter remains frozen when Chrome restores the page, and hitting reload several times does not help either.

Comment: Terrible, awful, no-good CSS based workaround. Have an 'online' element with an animation that hides it after 3 seconds. Use JS to perpetually reset it (remove/add?). When JS disappears, online goes away. Again, bad. But I don't know how to do anything else with JavaScript not even running.

Comment: @tmdesigned Please explain the idea in more detail. I am afraid I don't understand. And what I suspect: the CSS animation won't be running either... :-(

Comment: http://54.82.250.119/ . Basically a CSS animation that makes an 'offline' notice appear all at once after 3 seconds, but that is perpetually reset by JavaScript so long as JavaScript is running.

Comment: @tmdesigned I can confirm that your workaround works. Please post it as the first answer. Many thanks for your help and your effort! I will still have to check if HTTPS does not mess up anything, but it hopefully won't.

Comment: How about running a websocket server and using connection status to that to determine page content?

Comment: @miknik How do you update the page content if none of the JavaScript is running? Apart from that, sounds like a really heavy weight workaround. Both service worker and the CSS workaround are simpler and cause no additional work for the server.

Comment: @Ali You register a handler for `WebSocket.onclose` which will fire upon disconnect and have that change your page content. Personally I'd go with the service worker solution, then you can cache everything / some things / nothing and have total control of how the offline page appears, but I got the impression you didn't want to go down that route.

Comment: @miknik I don't have operational experience with service workers. Their overly complicated lifecycle scares me away. However, I agree, service workers seem to be a simpler solution than this workaround with websockets. Have you tested this websocket solution? Does it work? I am not sure the `WebSocket.onclose` will fire, since neither `beforeunload` nor `unload` fires. Chances are, `onclose` won't fire either...

Comment: Service workers are great once you get accustomed to them. Plenty of great tutorials out there and they provide lots of scope beyond just online/offline experience customisation. I just walked through your steps in chrome on android on a site of mine which uses websockets and it works, displays the offline message when I reopen chrome. I suspect the onclose event is firing when chrome is initially closed, rather than when the network connection is closed.

Comment: @miknik I am afraid of unpleasant surprises that service workers can cause. I am sure they have their quirks... I am also afraid of the web app being stuck in some inconsistent state due to the service workers, and then the clients are angry at me that *"It doesn't work."* My web app cannot provide meaningful offline experience anyway. The CSS workaround is acceptable for me; I already have another, similar workaround in place due to a Safari bug. In any case, I made a note to check `WebSocket.onclose`, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very inelegant workaround is to use a CSS animation that makes an "offline" element appear all at once after a set amount of time. With JavaScript, you can continually reset the animation, preventing it from ever showing unless/until JavaScript is no longer running to reset it.

The animation in the example below is set to 3 seconds, and uses keyframes to stay at `opacity:0` until 99% of the animation duration, at which point it changes to `opacity:1`.

In JavaScript we can reset the animation every 1-2 seconds with JavaScript by removing the class that is associated with it, forcing a reflow (by [fetching the offsetWidth](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-restart-a-css-animation-with-javascript-and-what-is-the-dom-reflow-a86e8b6df00f), for instance), and then adding the animation class back.

*Ideally* we could tell Chrome on these mobile devices to not cache the page at all. The various headers we tried in the comments on the question were not respected by a mobile device running with no Internet access.

Disabling the caching would be a more appropriate solution in both concept and execution. Having a running JavaScript interval that is perpetually forcing a reflow isn't great. But, it does give the user an indication that the JavaScript engine has stopped running, which is what the situation is here.

In the example below, the "Simulate stop JS" button just clears the interval that is continuing to reset the loading animation. This is a simulation only, but has the same effect as JavaScript not running (tested on an isolated server).

```js
const overlay = document.getElementById('offline-overlay');

const stopJS =  document.getElementById('stopJS');

const heartbeat = () => {
  overlay.classList.remove("animate-overlay");
  void overlay.offsetWidth; 
  overlay.classList.add("animate-overlay");
}

const heartbeatInterval = setInterval( heartbeat, 1000);

stopJS.addEventListener("click", function(){
  clearInterval(heartbeatInterval);
});
```

```css
@keyframes offline {
  0%   {opacity:0;}
  99%  {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

.animate-overlay{
  animation-name: offline;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

#offline-overlay{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#offline-overlay span{
  font-size:300%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
  <div id="offline-overlay" class="animate-overlay">
    <span>OFFLINE</span>
  </div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam varius quam sed nulla feugiat varius. Praesent vitae mi et libero porttitor maximus. Suspendisse eu pulvinar quam. Phasellus id ante a elit faucibus cursus. Curabitur porttitor vehicula ornare. Suspendisse nec risus ex. Aenean bibendum auctor ex eget aliquet. Donec laoreet sem ut tortor viverra aliquam.</p>

<button id="stopJS">Simulate Stop JS</button>
```

Comment: +1 and thanks! On the real webpage I already have another hack running in the background. That hack triggers a reflow every second, because Safari on iOS is buggy, and that hack was the only way to fix it. Adding your workaround to this already existing hack won't make my code uglier. However, there is one tweak I would like to ask. It seems to me that overlay totally covers the page, even if not visible. If that is the case, it is not acceptable: There are interactive elements on the page and the overlay would make those elements unusable.

Comment: Does the pointer-events:none not address this? I am able to still interact.

Comment: My apologizes, I wasn't aware of this: *"[pointer-events] the value none instructs the pointer event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead"* (from MDN). Sorry, I did not know that. OK, so we have a fix to this problem, and due to my other hack that is already running in the background (Safari bug workaround), it is not even making my code uglier. I am leaving the question open for a while so that your answer gets more upvotes.

Comment: As a side note: I am still surprised that none of the JS is re-run when the page is restored, but the CSS animations are running. It is definitely not what I expected to happen.

Comment: The CSS still working isn't *too* surprising to me because it's still allowing other CSS rules to apply. JavaScript not running in the first place is super suprising to me though. I'd love to see any other approaches people come up with.

Comment: I am thinking that direct code execution must be blocked but aren't listeners being registered ? If not all offline pages would be completely broken. I would mess around with mousemove listeners to see.

Comment: I believe the engine is paused, as even a running interval  stops iterating.